# Dynamically loading style sheets based on Server Controls

Tags: asp.net, css, parameter-passing, using-directives

I have a website that will need to load basic style components based on the model (determined on backend SQL server based on user input)

The concept is that this website can contained parameterized look-and-feel components which are predefined based on a landing page.

Can any one provide a basic idea or example of how to accomplish this?  One idea was to store style parameters at the database, but how could a style sheet pull this.  Another idea is to have these predefined style sheets corresponding to the landpage, but this would require a server control, and we wouldn't be able to implement this in the  to link the style sheet.

Comment: This was unclear: website is using asp.net and nHibernate to model backend sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style sheets cannot pull from a database, but you certainly can make a handler that serves up the CSS file rather than point to a physical CSS file.

The bigger problem here, however, is more of a business problem. You have to figure out the mapping of controls or layouts to CSS files prior to coding this. If you don't I can almost guarantee you are going to experience some pain down the road when you system cannot handle the requirements. Do the design work up front if you don't want too much pain.

Now, back to the issue. "Based on a landing page"? Do you mean different users hit different landing pages. If so, the styling can be applied to templates (easy in ASP.NET) or you can create a custom profile provider to marry style to user. I would think through those options. The storage of the file as a file or in the database is a separate issue.

Comment: Can you explain the use "serve up"  Would this solution actually write a file to the server, or just provide the textual information, can  you provide a reference? I agree this is more of a design issue.   A quick solution is the following is use of the following code:'<link id="myCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />' in the aspx with 'myCSS.Attributes.Add("href", "MyStyleFile.css");' in the code behind with MyStyleFile being the dynamic parameter being pulled from data stored in a cookie.   CSS Styles are provided 3rd party to offer 1 site to multiple clients w branding.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to tackle this, depending on your requirement. You can have CSS files and make a decision on what the setting is dynamically. This can be done by programmatically changing the link tag or by using an HTTP Handler (custom AXD file) and serving it up that way. Microsoft uses the later in some of their code.